# Background image not coming with prod env in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

In symfony2 the background image in css is working nice in dev environment, but not in prod environment

Here an CSS

```
background-image: url("../../bundles/acmeweb/images/logo-big.png");
```

In development(dev) environment background-image is working fine where as production(prod) environment, image is not coming.

I  need to append the url with 'web' in between image url for working in production like

```
background-image: url("../../web/bundles/acmeweb/images/logo-big.png");
```

Images are located in `MyBundle/Resources/public/images`

How this can be corrected?

Answer (score 2):

Symfony2 has full documentation on your question. Just read carefully :)
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#linking-to-assets

All images and styles sources should be located in bundle folders:

```
src/MyBundle/Resources/public/css
src/MyBundle/Resources/public/images
```

But only `web` folder is accessible from outside, so when you perform command

```
app/console assets:install web --symlink
```

it creates links to your files in **web** folder:

```
web/bundles/acmeweb/css
web/bundles/acmeweb/images
```

So in CSS you should always define relative path. In your case it will be:

```
background-image: url("../images/logo-big.png");
```

And in twig you should use `asset()` function to link your styles:

```
<link href="{{ asset('bundles/acmeweb/css/yourstylesheet.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

That's it

Again, read documentation carefully - it contains all these basic things ;)

Comment: why won't this work in prod? yet work in dev? 
{% stylesheets 'bundles/acmeweb/css/*' filter='cssrewrite' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}

Answer (score 0):

You are using relative path to get image,this may causing some problem.so instead of this try absolute path.

e.g. 
path = absolute path to reach logo-big.png
Here is CSS
background-image: url("path");

Comment: I am to new to SF2. How to give absolute path here?  Whether I need to change in config file?

Answer (score 0):

Change the path to:

```
background-image: url("/bundles/acmeweb/images/logo-big.png");
```

You might want to clear your cache too:

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

Answer (score 0):

To be clear to anyone else that comes here

define your files in

- mybundle/resources/public/css
- mybundle/resources/public/images

etc

refer to you image in your css relative e.g

```
body {
background: url('../images/mypicture.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
}
```

in your twig file

```
{% stylesheets 'bundles/mybundle/css/*' filter='cssrewrite' %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

now to make it run

```
php app/console cache:clear --env prod
php app/console cache:clear --env dev

php app/console assets:install

php app/console assetic:dump
```

now the kicker that got me

```
php app/console assetic:dump --env prod
```

This got it up and working for me, hope it helps someone